# Why below code goes into infinite loop?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, loops

Debug why the below mentioned code goes into an infinite loop

```
int a[10]; 
int i; 
for(i=0;i<=10;i++) { 
   a[i]=0; 
}
```

i am not able to find any valid explanation for it.
Although one possibility is a[9] pointing back to i ... but it doesn't seem convincing

Comment: should be `i<10` or you get out of bounds array access. It is probably overwriting the variable `i` at that time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ compilation bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506643/c-compilation-bug)

Comment: As you have allocated 10 digit initially and in the for loop you are assigning the 11th member that is a[10]. So change i < 10.

Comment: Both `a` and `i` are stored on stack, possibly next to each other. You can check the address of `a[10]` and `i`. If both are same then `i` has been overwritten.

Comment: In order to get hired, you must add a boundary check: `for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
  int val = 0; if(i > 10) goto fail; a[i]=val; `

Comment: @Lundin not to funny, you skipped the `{brackets}` thus making the code non-compiling because `val` is used out of scope.

Comment: @grek40 Apple requires that the code must compile? Awww :(

Comment: @grek40 Fixed: `int val; for(i=0;i<=10;i++) val = 0; if(i >= 10) goto fail; a[i]=val;`.

Answer (score 7):

Classic side effect of "Buffer overflow". In this case what is happening is that the value of i is getting overwritten. Check the range of variable a it's an array of 10 bytes 0 through 9. However you loop for 11 bytes 0 through 10.

Change the loop as

```
int a[10]; 
int i; 
for(i=0;i<10;i++) { 
   a[i]=0; 
}
```

and it won't go in infinite loop. Again this is a problem of "**buffer overflow**" and can have undefined behavior. In your case that undefined behavior is infinite loop.

Comment: `overwriting the value of i.`...can you explain?

Comment: Check my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158314/memory-confusion-for-strncpy-in-c/41159101#41159101 which explains a similar issue but different side effect.

Answer (score 2):

For the value of `i` equals to  `10`,

```
 a[i]=0;
```

is [off by one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) access. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen.

Comment: I'm so sick of the C UB "Anything can happen" attitude. While it is true for the language standard, most people don't execute the standard but a compiled program in a specific OS and both the compiler and the OS are free to define parts of the language UB (like not allowing a program to make demons fly out of your nose when executed in user mode). Just had to mention this somewhere :)

Comment: @grek40 Then, a question expecting that sort of answer should contain the additional information, like platform, compiler, optimization and likewise. Without that, you (we all) have to sate with UB.

Answer (score 2):

This code has undefined behavior. But if it is going into infinite loop the most suitable explanation would be that `a[10] = 0` is overwriting `i` with 0, since `i` is defined immediately after `a`, therefore, in memory is most probably placed as a contiguous element after array elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this so that you don't get undefined behavior:

```
int i, a[10];
for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++) 
    a[i]=0;
```