# Automatic resizing of array, initialized by auto-count?

Tags: c, arrays

So. I am teaching programming 1 to some college level pupils at the moment. And i specifically told them to go out and look online for references, specifically on the datastructure parts i am covering at the moment. Today one student emailed me with a link to tutorialspoint.com and asked about this piece of code he pulled from there:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
   int LA[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
   int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
   int i = 0, j = n;

   printf("The original array elements are :\n");

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
   }

   n = n + 1;

   while( j >= k) {
      LA[j+1] = LA[j];
      j = j - 1;
   }

   LA[k] = item;

    printf("The array elements after insertion :\n");

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
   }
}
```

Now, without knowing exactly where it's from i don't know exactly how they described it, but obviously it is insertion into an array of value at index k, shuffling upwards from k.

Now what he asked about was that i have told my students that when doing something like:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

the compiler will auto-count the size, by checking the supplied value list. This case means an array size of 4 elements. I have also told them that an array size is fixed when the array is first initialized, like:

```
int likethis[5]; 
int orthis[] = {1,2,3,4};
int orlikeso[MAX_ARR_SIZE];
```

Thus, to resize an array, dynamic memory management is needed, so that you would declare space for a new array (a part of the course they have yet to get to).

But the code from this tutorial site actually seems to do an auto-size by the compiler with the initializer list, then go about merrily resizing it in the loop, when shuffling.

So the final size of LA in their example would be 6 elements. Now, my student wants to know why this is valid. I have not tested this code myself, but apperantly it compiles on GCC according to my student. If so, how can that code be valid? Wouldn't this overwrite the boundaries of LA, when setting LA[5] in the shuffle loop?

Questions: Is it me who is an old geezer, and this is allowed in C since way back? Only in GCC? Seeing as i learned C in the 80s somewhere, i assume i might be wrong here, but to me it is writing past the assigned size of LA. Just wanted to check it on S.O.

Comment: The code doesn't resize the array. Arrays are fixed at compilation (except for [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which have their size fixed *once* at run-time) and their size can't be changed. What the code is doing is *bad* as it will go out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Could you provide the link to that piece of code on tutorialspoint.com please ?

Comment: I have found it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/array_data_structure.htm).

Comment: @LPs that is the verbatim code presented in the link, it's not code written by OP

Comment: @LPs it's from tutorialspoint, i'm pretty shocked to be honest.

Comment: Ah. So that is the link he used... Reading it quickly just now, i see no discalimer for that the code is causing undefined behaviour. Will mark it out to my students as an example next time in class as well.

Comment: Looking at the mistakes on the linked tutorial it seems to be written by someone with very limited experience in C.

Comment: @George What I've seen so far from tutorialspoint.com is 100% pure crap. A very bad site, avoid it like the plague.

Comment: The link to the tutorial is provided inside the exact duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> But the code from this tutorial site actually seems to do an auto-size by the compiler with the initializer list, then go about merrily resizing it in the loop, when shuffling.

The code only appears to do that. In reality, the code causes undefined behavior as soon as it touches index 5 of a five-element array.

> Now, my student wants to know why this is valid.

He should have started with a simpler "is this valid" question. The answer to it would be "no". The code will compile, and may even appear to work, but this code is invalid.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to demonstrate it to students at the early stages of learning C, because reading memory profiler reports (say, valgrind) is an advanced skill. On the other hand, if the students have enough determination to learn how to run their code through a memory profiler, they are in for a very rewarding experience of having good confidence in their code.

**Note:** I think this is a great teaching moment, because it lets you teach the student an important point about undefined behavior in C, and also reinforce the rule "you shouldn't trust things just because you found them on the internet" applies to code as well.

Comment: +1 for *"you shouldn't trust things just because you found them on the internet"* (I was just about to comment that the site makes it sound as if that was valid code). Programming still seems to have this air of mystery about it, where people assume if someone writes code, they know what they are doing.

Comment: And also reinforce rule *"Testing alone is never correct way to see what is legal in C."*

Comment: Agree, there is a teaching moment here, just have to figure how to word it so as to get the point across that "there is a lot of code online, use it to learn, but don't trust it to be accurate", which may be confusing to them at this stage...

Comment: Also, good to know that at least the fundamentals of C hasn't been changed while i've been away over the years :)

Comment: @RichardTyregrim: If they're still at that early a stage, tell them not to trust *any* online resource except the [language definition](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) itself (and even *that* has a few errata).  It's not a great learning resource on its own, but they may want to bookmark it for reference.

Comment: With careful testing, it's often possible to cause specific, explainable instances of undefined behavior.  A carefully taylor example would allow you to demonstrate that sometimes, but not always, writing out-of-range on an array might spill over into an adjacent variable.  It's important to recognize that undefined behavior is there to make compiler-writer's lives easier, not to trip up students.  Semi-related: [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Answer (score 2):

By attempting to write past the last element of the array, the code invokes *undefined behavior*, which means it may crash outright, silently corrupt data, or *appear* to run without any problems.

There may be some padding or scratch space that the extra element is being written to, which is why it isn't crashing, but this code is **not** valid.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing as automatic resizing with arrays in C. What is happening here is something known as **"buffer overflow"** . (Check the answer at [Memory confusion for strncpy in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158314/memory-confusion-for-strncpy-in-c/41159101#41159101) for more details on possible side effects of buffer overflow)

To show that the size of LA has not changed at all you can try printing the size at the beginning and at the end of the code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int LA[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
    int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
    int i = 0, j = n;

    printf("The original array elements are :\n");
    printf("Number of elements in LA = %ld\n",(sizeof(LA)/sizeof(int)));

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
    }

    n = n + 1;

    while( j >= k) {
        LA[j+1] = LA[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }

    LA[k] = item;

    printf("The array elements after insertion :\n");

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
    }
    printf("Number of elements in LA = %ld\n",(sizeof(LA)/sizeof(int)));
}
```

Comment: How can the size of `LA` change??? It is compile-time declared!

Comment: It won't change. The size of array i.e. LA remains same.. Thats what I wanted to show

Comment: Then why write "_To make sure that the size of LA has not changed..._"?

Comment: okay changed it. My purpose was to show that there is now change in size of the array which was the doubt mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the code is simply not valid. The array overflows but the bug is not visible (however if you enable compiler size optimization, it should improve probabilities that this code crashes).

In order to help you spotting the overflow, i suggest you run the code with Valgrind, as it will spot the overflow for you.

edit: I ran Valgrind with memcheck and it didn't spot that overflow.  Surprising for me.